# Google Assistant Account Linking via OAuth does not transfer from Speaker to Phone

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, actions-on-google, google-home, google-assistant

I am working on an Action on Google for one of our customers.
We are currently trying to transition from pure Google SignIn to Google SignIn + OAuth (Auth Code - [docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/oauth2?oauth=code)).
For that we use the OAuth implementation of said customer, which works fine.

When testing on the phone or the Google Assistant App, there is a pop-up that allows to link the action to the Auth provider. This works as intended.

However when testing on the speaker (Google Home + Google Home mini), the documentation says, that it should trigger a transfer to the phone via a notification on the device.
This does not happen unfortunately - we do not get any activity on our device.

We already asked the (AoG) support for help or known issues, but they could not help us with this and asked us to post our question over here.

### More Information:

- both devices are logged in with the same Google Account
- Google Assistant App + Google Home App is installed
- tested with Google Workspace account + with @gmail account
- tested on iOS (14.5.1 - iPhone 11)
- Notifications for Google Assistant are turned on
- Web & App Activity is turned on ([activity](https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols))
- "include Chrome History" is also checked

Did someone of you encounter a similar problem in the past?
If so, were you able to solve it?

Would be happy to hear from you.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly happens when you're trying to do this account linking on a speaker?

Comment: The documentation says that it should transfer to a phone. But nothing happens at all.

Comment: So the action fails silently? Does it exit?

Comment: The action does not exit directly, it just says, that there was some error. It then continues with the next question. Then it crashes and the action exits. 

When logging it via the backend, it shows, that it cannot access a certain param. 

The error message is talking about "sub of undefined" - this happens because the linking was not successful and the user is still a guest user.

What I can not explain is, why nothing shows up on my phone.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As stated before, the issue is simply, that no Transfer to the Phone happens. I will try to also use the newest AoG SDK version, to see if that fixes the issues.